# Cannot run SaltStack master on FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, saltstack

I want to install SaltStack in a brand new FreeBSD 10 machine. I am following the official documentation: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/freebsd.html

But when I try to launch the `salt_master` daemon it fails with this error message:

```
root@teldrassil:~ # service salt_master start
Starting salt_master.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/salt-master", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2837, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 449, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 742, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

Looking at the FreshPorts website it says that SaltStack needs two more packages/ports to work correctly:

```
sysutils/py-halite
sysutils/py-salt-api
```

But even with this two ports installed I got the same error when trying to start `salt_master`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue today with py-salt 2014.1.7 on FreeBSD 10.  I ended up updating my ports tree and running `make reinstall clean`.  This allowed the salt_master daemon start.  I would suggest doing the same if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

At writing time:

```
pkg update
pkg install py27-salt-2014.1.13
```

Later:

```
pkg update
pkg search salt
pkg install <package>
```

where package is the one following the pattern py<version>-salt.<version&gt (not the api one);